# Toggle KML overlay for Google Maps API v3 using checkbox

Tags: checkbox, maps, overlay, kml

Does anyone have some sample code for toggling a KML overlay layer with a checkbox?  I can get a kml layer on my map to toggle off when I uncheck the checkbox, but I can't get it to toggle back on. I've viewed all sorts of sample sites and code, but can't get this thing to work. The site in question is at www.fhitestsite.com/mdctest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your problem is that **map** var is not defined -
you defined **var map** inside a one function but trying to call it from other one. Define it outside of the function

```
...
var map;
var todayLayer;
var todayShown = 1;
var todayWdgt;
...
```

2) minor error. *todayWdgt* is NULL. Its just that you try to assign something that doesn't exist yet. 
You should run this code after the document is ready.

```
todayWdgt = document.getElementById("todayBtn");
todayWdgt.checked = true;
```

Try using firebug.